# jquery - fadein issue on mobile safari (iphone)

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I run this command in windows chrome it works fine, but on mobile safari it doesn't work at all (hidden div just appears, no fade effect):

```
jQuery(function($){$('#message').fadeIn("slow");});
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working? I'm using the default jquery library and this command is being executed inside a function after the document is loaded.

Comment: do you have some HTML code that this operates on? also is there a reason for the `"$"` inside your `"function($)"` code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this issue out, I ended up putting the fader inside a settimeout to delay the execution a few seconds and it worked great for my loading screen.